# Switching brakes from mechanical to hydraulics. Disk rotor question

Tags: brakes, rotor

Can I use the disk rotor from the current mechanical brake when I switch to hydraulic?

Comment: If the rotors match the pads of the new brakes, yes. (Some rotors are for organic/resin pads whereas others are for sintered pads.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes this will be fine.

The only caveat I can think of is rotor thickness, if you look closely on a rotor or read the manual, you should be able to find the minimum thickness.

This is different for different manufacturers but shouldn't affect a hydraulic disc brake, they automatically adjust for pad and rotor wear and will happily clamp a pair of new pads together with no disc in between.

See [this question about pad material](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16964/disc-brake-pad-and-rotor-compatibility). I wouldn't worry about that either.

Comment: Also look at the width of the braking surface around the outer edge of the rotor. Make sure the pad engages with the surface fully. Some rotors run a thinner braking edge than others. Notably Hope brakes / rotors.

Comment: Good point, though only really an issue on the OD. If the pad over laps the edge of the disc, it wont wear there and could prevent the brake from working properly if the unworn sections touch. This happened to a friend of mine when his LBS put the 180mm adaptor on upside down, wasn't a disaster, but the brake felt like crap.

Answer (score 1):

The type of braking mechanism should make no difference in what kind of rotor to use.

As mentioned before, ensure the new brake pads line up well with the original rotors.  If they are poorly aligned, you may experience brake-rub or squealing while stopping.  Rubbing alcohol can be used to keep your pads and rotors clean and quiet.

In the end, rotors are fairly cheap and you can swap new ones on it you do not like the feel.